# JEA amenities layout add custom css style

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

I was looking at the code and just don't get how to add a custom CSS class to **ul** tag?

```
  <?php if (!empty($this->row->amenities)): ?>
  <h3><?php echo JText::_('COM_JEA_AMENITIES')?> :</h3>
  <?php echo JHtml::_('amenities.bindList', $this->row->amenities, 'ul') ?>
  <?php endif ?>
```

Which generates:

```
<h3>Amenities</h3>
<ul>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 etc.
</ul>
```

I need:

```
<h3>Amenities</h3>
<ul class="check">
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 etc.
</ul>
```

I'm sure, it should be something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Source of the function is -

```
static public function bindList($value=0, $format='raw')
{
    if (is_string($value) && !empty($value)) {
        $ids = explode('-' , $value);
    } elseif (empty($value)) {
        $ids = array();
    } else {
        JArrayHelper::toInteger($value);
        $ids = $value;
    }

    $html = '';
    $amenities = self::getAmenities();
    $items = array();

    foreach ($amenities as $row) {
        if (in_array($row->id, $ids)) {
            if ($format == 'ul'){
                $items[] = "<li>{$row->value}</li>\n";
            } else {
                $items[] = $row->value;
            }

        }
    }

    if ($format == 'ul'){
        $html = "<ul>\n" . implode("\n", $items) . "</ul>\n";
    } else {
        $html = implode(', ', $items);
    }

    return $html;

}
```

As per the source of the function the way I can see is to replace `'<ul>'` to `'<ul class="check">'`

```
<?php 
$html = JHtml::_('amenities.bindList', $this->row->amenities, 'ul');
echo str_replace('<ul>','<ul class="check">',$html);    
?>
```

Or you can call `getAmenities` function and loop through result and create your own ul and li.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, your example worked fine.
Silly question, where did you find the source of the function?

Comment: @nox:Good to know.You can find the class inside-> 
Joomla folder->components\com_jea\helpers\html\amenities.php